# HTML5 Audio IOS(7) - Javascript Metronome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, settimeout, html5-audio

I'm creating a simple metronome web app that also displays a random note for training purposes. It works fine on desktop, but on my iPhone (IOS7) there seems to be an issue with the multiple audio elements I'm using.

I'm using one sound for the first accented beat of the measure, and then a different sound for the rest of the beats. The two audio elements look like this:

```
<div id="audioHide" class="hide">
    <audio id="beepOne" src="http://ivandurst.com/metronome/sounds/beat.wav" preload="auto" controls="controls">Your browser is not supported. Get a better standards compliant browser!</audio>
   <audio id="beepTwo" src="http://ivandurst.com/metronome/sounds/accent.wav" preload="auto" controls="controls">Your browser is not supported. Get a better standards compliant browser!</audio>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivandurst/SyCFg/) and [Live on my site](http://ivandurst.com/metronome-test/)

When I hit "play" on my iPhone in the jsfiddle, I hear the first sound every first beat, but it doesn't play the second sound for the rest of the beats. Everything else works perfectly. The reason I share both links is because it behaves different in the live environment - Sometimes it only plays the first sound every beat, sometimes it plays both sounds and works properly, and sometimes it says "The operation could not be completed" and/or plays nothing.

I'm not planning on selling this as an app or anything and it doesn't have to be perfectly accurate. I just want to share it as a web app with my friends who are trying to learn the notes on an instrument. Any thoughts on what's wrong here, or ideas for a possible workaround if it's a bug/known issue?